# Use of call and eval in makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I have the following Makefile:

```
define FOO
$1: ;
        @echo $1 $2
endef
$(call FOO,foo,foo1)
$(eval $(call FOO,bar,bar1))
```

Then I get:

```
tmp> make foo
foo foo1
tmp> make bar
bar bar1
```

Both of these calls expand properly, handle parameters correctly, and are parsed as part of the Makefile.   The `$(eval $(call ...))` format seems to be more popular in the Makefiles I've seen.    What is the advantage of doing this as opposed to using `$(call MACRO)` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one only works because you added an extra semicolon to the first line.  Similarly, if you expand your defined command to contain more than one line then it will not work.

For example if you write:

```
define FOO
$1:
        @echo $1 $2
endef
```

this will not work with `$(call ...)` but it will work with `$(eval $(call ...))`.  Similarly if you write:

```
define FOO
$1: ;
        @echo $1
        @echo $2
endef
```

this will not work with `$(call ...)` but it will work with `$(eval $(call ...))`.

Basically, `call` by itself will cause make to treat the entire result as one single long line, as if the newlines were converted to spaces (although this doesn't actually happen).  If the result of that is valid makefile syntax then it works.  If the result is NOT valid makefile syntax, you lose.

`eval`, on the other hand, will re-interpret the result of the `call` function so that the newlines are treated as actual makefile newlines.